# Double click tab to Close all but this

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I find myself going to the open windows tab bar in Visual Studio often and right clicking it to get the menu and then finding Close all but this to clean up my workspace after I have made a bunch of changes and there is too much clutter in terms of open tabs.

*I would like to be able to assign a mouse shortcut to this, similar to one I use in Firefox, so that if I simply double-click an open tab that would remain open but the rest would close.*

[image: use-new-shortcut-in]

Visual Studio Keyboard Options do not seem to allow a purely mouse shortcut and I cannot find a way to narrow it to the tab bar either.

- Are there any ways to make it happen in Visual Studio natively or any add-ins that achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, Visual Studio 2013 does not support binding mouse events as shortcuts. It is even more restrictive in that a modifying key needs to be part of a shortcut sequence (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, ...).

I've no real answer to the second part of your question. I think your best bet would be a third-party tool that can map your mouse double-click event to a specific, unused key combination and map that key combination within Visual Studio to the action you are trying to map to.

From a quick search, [Microsoft TechNet - Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj851234.aspx) might be an option for you. It doesn't seem to work with every mouse but it might be a starting point.